# Dois WHERE com duas condicionais independentes

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Fala Pessoal, estou montando uma query com objetivo de trazer 2 colunas que fazem a mesma consulta porém com 2 condicionais diferentes. 
ex:

```
SELECT 
         COUNT(MAX(l.created_at))as last_login_x1,
         COUNT(MAX(l1.created_at)) as last_login_x2
      FROM usuarios as u
           INNER JOIN register as r ON r.id = u.user_id
           LEFT JOIN last_login as l ON l.user_id = u.user_id
     LEFT JOIN last_login as l1 ON l1_id = u.user_id
      WHERE u.status = 'approved'
       AND l1.amount  > 1
       AND l.amount > 1 
     GROUP BY u.user_id
    HAVING MAX(l1.created_at) < DATE(CURRENT_DATE) - interval '30 days'
AND MAX(l.created_at) >= DATE(CURRENT_DATE) - interval '30 days'
```

A ideia é contar os usuários que **não fizeram** login nos últimos 30 dias versus os que **fizeram login** nos últimos 30 dias

Comment: Pode adicionar o DDL da sua base, para que seja fornecido um exemplo de query?

Comment: Uma possibilidade é referenciar uma única vez a tabela last_login e nos campos do select utilizar um `SUM(CASE MAX(l.created_at) < DATE(CURRENT_DATE) - interval '30 days') THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS last_login_x1`. Idem para last_login_x2.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia

Uma forma de eliminar varredura em uma tabela seria reaproveitar o dado para ambas as situações. Neste caso, é possível a aplicação.

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN l.created_at >= DATE(CURRENT_DATE) - interval '30 days' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS last_login_x1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN l.created_at < DATE(CURRENT_DATE) - interval '30 days' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS last_login_x2
FROM usuarios AS U
INNER JOIN register AS R 
    ON r.id = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id,MAX(created_at) AS created_at FROM last_login WHERE amount > 1 GROUP BY created_at) as l 
    ON l.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE 
    u.status = 'approved'
```

Qualquer coisa, só chamar, creio que atenderá o seu problema.